# How to change data in the first column of a file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am trying to change in the first column of an input text two characters and doing that for multiple files -250 in this case-, using `awk` but I get errors. My level is beginner, so I started without including the multiple files, starting just for a single one.

**Input text: *.xyz**

```
6    -2.163968    -0.214364    0.000000
1    -1.578434    -2.353198    0.000000
1     1.575214     2.351350    0.000000
6    -4.697660     0.932898    0.000000
1    -3.168017     3.994185    0.000000
1    -5.599375     2.978998    0.000000
```

so the text will have different characters like 6 or 1 or more in the first column only and I want to replace only those with C for 6 and H for 1. What I try changes all of the numbers 6 and 1 or just prints error.

```
awk -F, -vOFS=, '{for(n=1;n<=1;n++)sub(/\6/,"C",$1)}1' *.xyz 

awk ' NF >= 4 { $(NF - 3) = "sub(/\C,"6",$1)"; print; }' *.xyz
```

which does not work.

What do I need to change?

Comment: Welcome at Stackoverflow. Could you please put a proper question as question title (i.e. "How to change two characters ...  ?")?

Comment: What is your desired output for the input that you've shown?

Comment: Get the book "Effective Awk Programming", 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins. You'll be able to do what you want after reading the first few pages. Right now your scripts make absolutely no sense so it's hard to know how to help you..

Comment: The two substitutions `s/^6/C/g` and `s/^1/H/g` do the required replacements.

Comment: Felix: You are correct. Too many mistakes
Tom Fenech: the desired output is exactly like the suggestion of amdixon :)
Ed Morton: Thanks for the ref., I ll dive in.
Klas Lindbäck: Thanks for the suggestion. That was the idea amdixon used.
９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９: makes no sence agree.

Answer (score 2):

**plan**

> - use sed to in-place replace these fields

note 1.xyz and 2.xyz contain identical contents as posted in question

**replace_first.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in ./*.xyz;
do
  printf "processing $i\n";
  sed -i -e 's/^1\(\s\)/H\1/g' \
         -e 's/^6\(\s\)/C\1/g' "$i";
done;
```

**output**

```
$ ./replace_first.sh 
processing ./1.xyz
processing ./2.xyz
$ cat 1.xyz 
C    -2.163968    -0.214364    0.000000
H    -1.578434    -2.353198    0.000000
H     1.575214     2.351350    0.000000
C    -4.697660     0.932898    0.000000
H    -3.168017     3.994185    0.000000
H    -5.599375     2.978998    0.000000
$ cat 2.xyz 
C    -2.163968    -0.214364    0.000000
H    -1.578434    -2.353198    0.000000
H     1.575214     2.351350    0.000000
C    -4.697660     0.932898    0.000000
H    -3.168017     3.994185    0.000000
H    -5.599375     2.978998    0.000000
```

Comment: Thanks so much amdixon both for correcting the post and the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{ if( $1 == 6 ) $1 = "C"; else $1 = "H"; print}' *.xyz
```

if space separator are important

```
awk '{ sub( /^6/, "C");sub( /^1/, "H"); print}' *.xyz
```

Comment: NeronLeVelu, thanks alot it works as well as amdixon's suggestion.